# How to find a Liferay site id from its "Friendly URL"?

Tags: liferay

I am developing a Liferay module. I have a Liferay site's `Friendly URL`, and I want to get its `Site ID` (for instance `20143`).

[image: Liferay site Friendly URL]

[GroupLocalServiceUtil](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/7.0/javadocs/portal-kernel/com/liferay/portal/kernel/service/GroupLocalServiceUtil.html#getGroup-long-) has several `getGroup` methods, but none seem to take a `friendly URL` as parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GroupLocalServiceUtil](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/7.0/javadocs/portal-kernel/com/liferay/portal/kernel/service/GroupLocalServiceUtil.html#getFriendlyURLGroup-long-java.lang.String-) has `getFriendlyURLGroup` method, you can get group, group id is site id.

```java
Group group =GroupLocalServiceUtil.getFriendlyURLGroup(companyId,friendlyURL);
```